# Tutorials and real-life applications of MVC .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have just installed Microsoft Visual studio Express 2012 for Web and I spent a lot of time searching for some solid examples and tutorials i order to learn more about this great technology and to create my first app. The most interesanting and professional examples I could find are these

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application (Contoso University)

and

http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf

BUT I plan to create my first app which will be web app which will contain information about patients with all their personal data, visits, diagnosis etc with an accent on reporting and auhorisation roles.

I plan to use Contoso University as a reference because right now I don't have any other alternative. Anyone who could recommend me some website with many different complete-full examples of MVC .NET Web apps is more then welcome.

Any help is appreciated and many thanks in advance!

Cheers:)
Adi

Comment: Try the official site http://www.asp.net/mvc. You have a lot of tutorials and videos. A lot of stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pluralsight mvc](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=mvc4-building&highlight=scott-allen_mvc4-building-m1-intro!scott-allen_mvc4-building-m8-infrastructure!scott-allen_mvc4-building-m2-controllers!scott-allen_mvc4-building-m6-ajax!scott-allen_mvc4-building-m7-security!scott-allen_mvc4-building-m9-tests#mvc4-building-m1-intro)

This is a really good set of tutorials to get you up to speed.

Here is also a good tutorial on the web api just incase you want to use that too

[Pluralsight mvc web api](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspnetwebapi&highlight=jon-flanders_aspnetwebapi-m1-introduction#aspnetwebapi-m1-introduction)

These are free tutorials, but that sight has many brilliant tutorials for dot net dev.

Hope its helpful to you.

Comment: +1.  I was literally about to post the same thing.  Pluralsight  is an amazing resource especially if you like video training and details explained thoroughly.

Comment: And they are always updating their tutorials. Love them.

Comment: I have already started learning form link you suggested. Thank you, very good resource!